# Where in the AlethZero GUI do I get access to the public keys for my owned accounts?

Tags: ethereum

I've tried selecting and copying, double-clicking, and have looked through the menus to no avail. Probably something simple but I'm new here and trying to get my bearings in the wild west :smile:

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

1. Double-click on address in **Owned Accounts** (single-click does not work)
2. **⌘-C** to copy full address